# Under which database tables are coming when they are generated in a query

Tags: sql-server-2005

If I'm creating a table with the help of query command, then under which database can i find it?

Answer (score 0):

depends on what database was defined in ConnectionString credentials.
eg

```
SERVER=myserv; PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; DATABASE=mydb; UID=sqluser; PWD=sqlpass;
```

in this case all queries will be run under database named MYDB
you may also change current db with following query:

```
USE SomeOtherDb
```